# Umbraco: "System.InvalidOperationException: The view found at '~/Views/Homepage.cshtml' was not created."

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This is my first post in this stackoverflow. I hope to do it correctly.

I spend hours look for a solution without results. I'm using `Umbraco` version 7.5.7 assembly: 1.0.6219.11990

I use Visual Studio Express 2015 For Web, if I run the project with debugger (f5), I have no problem and my developed site works perfectly. If I run the project without debugger (ctrl+f5) nothing works

[run with or without debugger buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dufC5.png)

This is the exception thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view found at '~/Views/Homepage.cshtml' was not created.

I had the same issue in all pages that I create but I'm able to enter in Umbraco settings pages correctly in any mode.

Any ideas?

[error's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Rj0.png)

[EDIT] Included code of master (layout) and homepage but I have the same problem in all pages

Here's the "master" code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using Umbraco.RelationEditor.Extensions;
@using Comp.Umb.Lisa.Models;
@using Comp.Umb.Lisa
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.Partial(LisaContansts.Partials.MetaData)

<link rel="icon" href="~/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="~/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/camera.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/google-map.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/subsribe_mailform.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/blocks.css">
<link href="~/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
    <!-- analytics -->
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<html class="lt-ie9">
<div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
  <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/..">
    <img src="images/ie8-panel/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820"
         alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."/>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src='~/js/device.min.js'></script>
<div class="page">
    <!--========================================================
                          HEADER
    =========================================================-->
    <header>

        <div id="stuck_container" class="stuck_container">
            <div class="wr">
                <div class="brand">
                    <img class="" src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("logoHeader", true)).Url" />
                </div>
                <nav class="nav">
                    @{
                    var relatedPagesLang = Model.Content.Related<IPublishedContent>("LisaLangRel");
                    if (relatedPagesLang.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        var langRel = relatedPagesLang.First();
                        <a href="@langRel.Url"><img class="lang" src="@Umbraco.Media(langRel.GetPropertyValue("iconaLingua", true)).Url" /></a>
                    }


                }

                @Html.Partial("_MenuNavigazione")

            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>

@RenderBody()

<!--========================================================
                          FOOTER
=========================================================-->
<footer>
    <style type="text/css">
        footer{
            background: url(@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("immagineSfondo", true)).Url) 50% 50% no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <section class="mobile-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_4">
                    <h6>
                        @CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("titoloNavigazione", true)
                    </h6>
                    @Html.Partial("_FooterNavigazione")
                </div>
                <div class="prefix_1 grid_3">
                    <h6>
                        @CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("titoloServizi", true)
                    </h6>
                    @Html.Partial("_FooterServizi")

                </div>
                <div class="prefix_1 grid_3">
                    <div class="prefix_1 grid_3">
                        <h6>@CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("titoloIndirizzo", true)</h6>
                        <div>
                            @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("indirizzoFooter", true).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section class="copyright">
                <div class="container">
                    © <span id="copyright-year"></span> @CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("testoCopyright", true)
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>




</footer>
```

And here's the homepage code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Homepage>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@using Umbraco.Web.Models;
@using Comp.Umb.Lisa.Models;
@{
Layout = "Master.cshtml";

}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
<!--========================================================
                        CONTENT
  =========================================================-->
<main>
@Html.Partial("_Slider")
@{
    DynamicPublishedContent block = CurrentPage.Descendants("titolo_Immagine_Testo_bottone")[0];
    @Html.Partial("_TitleImgLeftTextButton", block);

}

<section class="well wow fadeIn ">
    @{ 
        DynamicPublishedContentList services = CurrentPage.Descendants("servizi").Any()? CurrentPage.Descendants("servizi").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("servizio").Take(4):new DynamicPublishedContentList();
    }
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach(DynamicPublishedContent service in services)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_ServizioHP", service)
            }

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
@{ 
    DynamicPublishedContent textImg = CurrentPage.Descendants("testoImmagineSfondo").FirstOrDefault();
    @Html.Partial("_TextBackgroundImage", textImg);

    if (CurrentPage.Descendants("titolo_Immagine_Testo_bottone").Count() >= 2)
    {
        //DynamicPublishedContent secondBlock = CurrentPage.Descendants("titolo_Immagine_Testo_bottone")[1];
        @Html.Partial("_TitleImgLeftTextButton", (DynamicPublishedContent)CurrentPage.Descendants("titolo_Immagine_Testo_bottone")[1]);
    }


}
<hr />
    @if (CurrentPage.Descendants(LisaContansts.DocumentTypes.Clienti).Count() > 0)
    {
        @Html.Partial(LisaContansts.Partials.Clienti, (DynamicPublishedContent)CurrentPage.Descendants(LisaContansts.DocumentTypes.Clienti)[0])
    }
</main>
```

Comment: In general it is a good idea to include some lines of source code from your cshtml file. The information you provided is not really helpful for others to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for reply, I added the code, I'm sorry for not properly correct post

Comment: For future searches, I hope it is allowed to link here your umbraco forum topic: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/templates-partial-views-and-macros/84476-exception-views-was-not-created

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue, what fixed it for me was editing the web.config and finding this value:

`Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode`

Changing it to `Dll` or `LiveAppData` instead of the default `PureLive` fixes it.

You can also set `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable` to `false` if you're not using the models builder functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue, I tried changing the ModelsMode, but it only changed the error message.  The solution for me was simple matter of going back into the CMS and resaving the doctype. So ultimately I left it on PureLive and after saving everything came back.